# How to use BackHandler in react-native-router-flux with tabbar

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

Im trying to implement Backhandler with Listener, In **componentWillMount im adding the listener and in componentWillUnMount im removing the listener** but **componentWillUnMount is not called when we push to other component**. So **Listener is there in other Components also, Is there a problem of react-native-router-flux with tabbar**

Answer (score 4):

To make back handler work with a centralised configuration, I'd normally have the handler in a component called `AppNavigation` which is the parent for Router component.

It looks something like:

```
<AppNavigation>
  <Router>
      <Scene key="root">
        {/* other scenes */}
      </Scene>
    </Router>
</AppNavigation>
```

Handling the back button in AppNavigation would then be relatively straightforward:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {BackAndroid} from "react-native";
import {Actions} from "react-native-router-flux";

class AppNavigation extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        //listens to hardwareBackPress
        BackAndroid.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {
            try {
                Actions.pop();
                return true;
            }
            catch (err) {
                console.debug("Can't pop. Exiting the app...");
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        console.log("Unmounting app, removing listeners");
        BackAndroid.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress');
    }

    render() {
        return this.props.children;
    }
}

export default AppNavigation;
```

P.S. Don't forget to differentiate between android and iOS though, since I believe iOS does not have a back button.

Comment: Great it helps! :) would you mind accepting my reply as the answer? Thanks!